# Better to change protected to public? or create another method that calls the superclass

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a game using the best practices to my knowledge. 
I have:

- a `VisibleObject` with a `protected void draw(Canvas c)` function
- a `MapTile` that `extends VisibleObject` to draw itself.
- a `Map` class that contains a LinkedList of MapTiles, `tiles`.

In the `Map` class i wanted a loop like this:

```
public void draw(Canvas c){
        for(MapTile tile : tiles){
            tile.draw(c);
        }
    }
```

But i realised i could not call draw upon each tile because it's a protected method in `VisibleObject`. 
I can think of 3 possible solutions:

1. Just change `protected` to `public` in `VisibleObject`.
2. Create a public method of MapTile that just calls `super.draw(c)` (I think that's valid syntax?)
3. change the for loop in Map to something like this,  which i believe would make it valid.

New Loop:

```
MapTile current;
for(MapTile tile : tiles){
    current = tile;
    current.draw(c);
}
```

Which solution would be better programming practice?

Comment: `this.draw` not `super.draw`; #3 also won't work.

Comment: Why do you think that method visibility affects performance?

Comment: If MapTile is extending VisibleObject the call to a protected method in VisibleObject from MapTitle is supposed to be allowed. Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for version 2. Version 1 would introduce access modifiers in the parent that perhaps should not be there (e.g. going from `protected` to `public`), while version 3 does not make much sense, since you are still using an instance of `MapTile` (even if it did, it looks awkward and unnatural).

If any of the children of a class need to expose a protected method of the parent the best idea is to create a public method that calls the parent method.

Comment: I don't see why a wrapper would be good style, if the only purpose is to bypass the access modifier.

Comment: @TobiasN.Sasse: It's not a wrapper, at least from the naming. `VisibleObject` sounds like an abstract class to me.

Comment: You are correct in that VisibleObject is abstract :) And i also feel that access rights should be preserved.

Answer (score 2):

There is also another option: `Map`, `MapTile` and `VisibleObject` to stay in the same package. Also they seem to be very related: `MapTile` is a part of a `Map` and `MapTile` is a `VisibleObject`. This way you can see the `MapTile.draw` method from the `Map` class. I wouldn't make the `draw` method visible outside this package.

Comment: The calling code would also need to be in the same package, so this is not a solution.

Comment: The calling code might call public methods on the Map, for example Map .draw might be public.

Comment: A good point thanks! but i'm sort of trying to keep code that is specific to my game separate to the code i could re-use later for another game by using the separate packages.

Answer (score 1):

If the method needs to be called by outside objects, then it must be public. I don't see a way around this. If on the the other hand the method will only be called by other methods inside of the class, then leave it protected or make it private.

I look on this similar to the Swing `JComponent#paint(...)` and `JComponent#paintComponent(...)` method. The former is called directly by the Swing paint manager and thus must be public while the latter is called only internally by the `paint(...)` method and so is protected.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that draw() should be public. The draw() method seems very relevant for any object that want to create or hold a MapTile object.

To disable others from accessing the specific MapTiles in the Map however, is something else. Here the burden lays on the Map class. The LinkedList of MapTiles should probably be private. Some getter method (`public LinkedList<MapTiles> getMapTiles()`) could be provided to give access to (a *copy* of?) the list, if other objects should need it. If your really worried about how other objects could access the MapTiles, the Map and MapTiles should be in the same package, so that these objects can exchange info, while other classes in other packages only have access to certain public getter methods.